# AngularJS function runs before loading the Page for deciding either redirect to login or dashboard

Tags: javascript, angularjs

we are using AngularJS 1.4

We have two different `ng-app login and Dashboard` So If user is already login then we redirect to **Dashboard app** and if user is not login then redirect to **login app**  .

So we send authorization token for validating the user is login or not . Authorization token is deleted after every 2 hr at server but on client site there is token . So it loads and redirect to Dashboard and then API sends to server and it check now token is deleted so then it again redirect to login

We want that first it checks for token validation and then decide rather to redirect to login or dashboard

**Edit**
Now what happens when user opens page www.abc.com then first it open login page and then Angular calls rest API to check that User is Authenticate or not , if user Authenticate then it redirects to Dashboard . So it looks that first login page open then after 1 seconds it open Dashboard page

Now we want that before loading a page it sends user Authentication Call and on basis of response it redirects to login or Dashboard

Comment: And your question is??

Comment: Now what happens when user opens page www.abc.com then first it open login page and then Angular calls rest API to check that User is Authenticate or not , if user Authenticate then it redirects to Dashboard